# I do not understand how parameters work in this Polymorphism code

Tags: c#, polymorphism

My brother wrote this code for me to show an example of polymorhism. But I don't really understand how it all works, starting with the parameters. Can someone dissect the code and tell me a little bit about how it all works together and how it functions?

**EDIT: Here's a specific question: mammals.Add(new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue")); What do the numbers do? What is their purpose and how do they work with the code?**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Mammal> mammals = new List<Mammal>();

            mammals.Add(new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue"));
            mammals.Add(new HumanFemale("Krysten", 72, 15, "White", "Blue"));
            mammals.Add(new Cat("Larry", 7, 2, "Orange", "Hazel"));
            mammals.Add(new Dog("Walt", 3, 5, "Brown", "Hazel"));
            mammals.Add(new HumanMale("Ryan", 72, 31, "White", "Blue"));
            mammals.Add(new Cat("Blacky", 5, 10, "Black", "Brown"));

            foreach (Mammal m in mammals)
            {
                m.Speak();
                m.Walk();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } // end of Program class declaration




    public abstract class Mammal
    {
        public Mammal(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.HeightInInches = heightInInches;
            this.Age = age;
            this.Color = color;
            this.EyeColor = eyeColor;
        }

        private int _HeightInInches;
        private int _Age;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the age (in years).
        /// </summary>
        public int Age
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _Age; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Age!");
                }
                _Age = value; 
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the height.
        /// </summary>
        public int HeightInInches
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _HeightInInches; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid height!");
                }
                _HeightInInches = value; 

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the skin or fur color.
        /// </summary>
        public string Color { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the eye color.
        /// </summary>
        public string EyeColor { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Causes the mammal to speak.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The mammal spoke.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Causes the mammal to walk.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Walk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The mammal is walking.");
        }

    } // end of Mammal class declaration


    public class Dog : Mammal
    {
        public Dog(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor) 
            : base (name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
        {
        }

        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} the Dog says: 'Ruff!'", this.Name);
        }

        public override void Walk()
        {
            if (this.Age == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} newborn puppy was just born and is too little to walk yet!", this.Name, this.Color);
            }

            else if (Age > 0 && Age <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} puppy is {2} years old and is running around like a hyper puppy, chewing up all the furniture. Oh nooo!", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 5 && Age <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} dog is {2} years old and walks conservatively", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} dog is {2} years old and walks very slowly, and has arthiritus in the joints.", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }
        }

    } // end of Dog class


    public class Cat : Mammal
    {
        public Cat(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
            : base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
        {
        }

        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} the Cat says: 'Meow!'", this.Name);
        }

        public override void Walk()
        {

            if (this.Age == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} newborn Kitten was just born and is too little to walk yet!", this.Name, this.Color);
            }

            else if (Age > 0 && Age <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} Kitten is {2} years old and is running around like a hyper kitten!", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 5 && Age <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} cat is {2} years old and walks conservatively", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} cat is {2} years old and walks very slowly", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }
        }
    } // end of Cat class

    public abstract class Human : Mammal
    {
        public Human(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
            : base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
        {
        }


        public override void Walk()
        {

            if (this.Age == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} newborn baby was just born and is too little to walk yet!", this.Name, this.Color);
            }

            else if (Age > 0 && Age <= 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} toddler is {2} years old and is crawling around!", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 2 && Age <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} kid is {2} years old and is walking around!", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 5 && Age <= 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} kid is {2} years old and walks briskly", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 12 && Age <= 19)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} audlt is {2} years old and walks briskly", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 20 && Age <= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} adult is {2} years old and walks conservatively", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }

            else if (Age > 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the {1} old person is {2} years old and walks with a cane", this.Name, this.Color, this.Age);
            }
        }

        public  override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The human spoke");
        }
    } // end of Human class

    public class HumanMale : Human
    {
        public HumanMale(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
            : base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
        {

        }

        public override void Speak()
        {
            if (this.Age == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the newborn baby boy was just born and is too young to speak", this.Name);
            }
            if (this.Age > 0 && this.Age <= 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the toddler boy babbles 'goo goo ga ga'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 3 && this.Age <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the toddler boy says, 'I like fire trucks'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 5 && this.Age <= 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the young boy says: I want to be a fireman'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 12 && this.Age <= 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the teenage boy says: I want a girlfriend'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the adult male says, 'Hey hey hey!'", this.Name);
            }

        }

    } // end of HumanMale class

    public class HumanFemale : Human
    {
        public HumanFemale(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
            : base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
        {

        }

        public override void Speak()
        {
            if (this.Age == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the newborn baby girl was just born and is too young to speak", this.Name);
            }
            if (this.Age > 0 && this.Age <= 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the toddler girl babbles 'da da goo goo ga ga'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 3 && this.Age <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the girl says 'I wanna be a princess'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 5 && this.Age <= 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the young girl says: I AM a princess'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 12 && this.Age <= 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the teenage girl says: Like, totally. Did you see that other chick? Like, what was she wearing'", this.Name);
            }

            if (this.Age > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, the adult female says, 'Yep, I'm a woman.'", this.Name);
            }

        }

    } // end of HumanFemale class


} // end of namespace declaration
```

Comment: Why don't you ask your brother?

Comment: You should be more specific. Asking "how it all works" is far too vague. Isolate *one* concept you don't understand, and show a much smaller piece of code with *just* that concept.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake, what is a switch going to solve in this example?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake How can you use a switch to specify ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific question in the EDIT:

```
mammals.Add(new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue"));
```

The line can be rewritten as:

```
Cat aCat = new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue"); 
mammals.Add(aCat);
```

In the first line you are calling the constructor of Cat:

```
public Cat(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)
            : base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)
```

passing "Snow white" as name, 1 as heightInInches, 0 as age, "White" as color and "blue" as eyeColor. The constructor is empty (it does nothing, but it is based upon the Mammal constructor (this is the meaning of `base(name, heightInInches, age, color, eyeColor)`), which is called passing the same parameters. This means that `public Mammal(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)` is executed, so you end up with an instance of Cat where all the properties have the values that were passed as parameters.

Now you execute

```
 mammals.Add(aCat);
```

Here you are adding the instance of Cat to a list of Mammal. You ca do that because Add expect a Mammal as argument, and aCat is a Mammal, since its class is derived from Mammal.

Comment: BTW, the debugger is a good tool for studyin, too. In your case put a breakpoint on the first line of the Main meethod and try to step into every instruction with F11. This should help you understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Mamal is the general type of all dog, cat, humanfemal, humanmale. All have some properties and functions in common.

public Mammal(string name, int heightInInches, int age, string color, string eyeColor)

this line is the constructor of mamal class. The properties name, heightininches, age, color, eyecolor are common in all mammal.

All mammals can walk(have a same function ), but all walk in different ways.So we need to override this function to give the desired functionality to different mammals.

public override void Walk() 
this line is how walk functionality is overrided.

The mammal class is abstract . That means there is no animal called mammal . Its just a broad definition.

hope it helps.

Comment: List<Mammal> mammals : this line defines a list of mammals.Which means it can hold any kind of mammals.                                             new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue") : this segment creates a mammal of type cat with the constructor. so the complete linemammals.Add(new Cat("Snow white", 1, 0, "White", "blue")); creates a new cat and adds it to the mammals list.

Comment: In my opinion you should work on classes, constructors, properties, methods, class instantiation first.Generally search and "study object oriented approach in c#" before diving into polimorphism.

Comment: Indeed. Forget polymorphism. The OP needs to learn the basics first.

Comment: Ah, okay.I understand a bit better now. I've been at this same concept for a while. I should probably focus more in depth with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

So, **Mamal** is your base class, which will hold all the common properties for each of the **Animals**.

You then derive classes for your Animals (Cat, Dog) etc so these will inherit the same properties as the base.

The base uses virtual methods, so that you can **override** their functionality in the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what your brother is trying to show you is that when you derive classes from a parent class, you can use all of the fields and properties from the parent class in different, and usually more sophisticated, ways.  That's what polymorphism means.

With the parameters, your brother made it so each class that derives from `Mammal` takes the same parameters: name, height, age, color, and eye color.  In the `Mammal` class, he then made it so each parameter sets its respective property, i.e. if you pass in `"Bob"` as the name parameter, the `Name` of the `Mammal` is then Bob.  When it comes to all the other classes, he simply used the `base()` constructor to make the mammals initialize in the same way as `Mammal`.

Your brother then got into the methods, which are what do the actual doing.  He made them `virtual`, which allows polymorphism.  Basically, this says that any child class can "`override`", or change, the method for itself.  By overriding a method, the child class says "when you use this method on me, do it this way instead of how my parent class did it."  He demonstrates this by overriding the methods in each child class, and then calling (or doing) the methods using each child class.  Because the methods are overridden, you will get "meow" for a cat or "ruff" for a dog instead of "the mammal spoke".

Also note that since the child class derive from the `Mammal` class, they have the same properties, so every `Mammal` has an age, height, etc that it can use.  Your brother used this in the methods to customize them.

It's a lot of info, but I hope it's understandable.